# I want my features to work in the new table row

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle where the user opens a grid and selects an option, after the user selects an option if they click on the "Add question" button, then it will display the option in a new table row.

As you can see in the new table row it shows the text box and the open grid link as well. I have done this because lets say you have added an option but then realise you have chosen the wrong option, I want the user to be able to click on the "Open Grid" link in whichever row is relevant and click on the option they prefer. So in other words I want the users to be able to select an option within a table row the exactly the same way as if they were choosing their options using the above feature before adding the option in a new row.

I am using the .on() function to do this but my problem is that if I try to open the grid in one of the outputted rows, it would not open the grid. So how can I get it so that the user can seelct an option from the table row like they do when selecting an option from the above feature.

My code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8cKm/9/), if anyone does have an idea then feel free to use the fiddle to test your ideas.

Thank You

Comment: I know this isn't answering your specific question (which I could still help you with), but why not just have a `remove row` option?  This would involve less code and will probably easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Because in the future the user is not only going to add an option type but they are going to add a question, an option, an answer, a question weight and a question duration, if the user removes a row, then they have to fill the details again, while if they can edit a row it might take them less time then removing a row and filling it in again, to be honest it might be a good idea to allow the user to either edit features in the row or possible remove a row if they make a huge mistake, what do you think?

Comment: That sounds good to me ;p  Though not always true, the more flexible your gui is, the better the user's experience will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

```
 $('.showGrid').on('click', function...
```

with

```
 $(document).on('click', '.showGrid', function...
```

to get `.live()`-like functionality. You also need to either change the `.showGridRow` class on your appended links to `.showGrid`, or make the following additional change:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.showGrid,.showGridRow', function...
```

This leaves the problem that the 'grid' is popping up in the same place no matter where you click. I solved this by adding the following line to your 'show" code:

```
        $('#optionTypeTbl').css({
            left: $(this).position().left,
            top: $(this).position().top + 20
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/f8cKm/15/

Comment: Hi, the only problem is that if I click on the "Open Grid" links in a row and select an option, it is suppose to change the value in that row's textbox not the value on the top textbox

Comment: @mblase75 That's probably the best way, but you could also get the context of the clicked element to determine the location of the box being used.

Comment: How do I give each input a different name because it is just one line of code that displays an input for each row?

Comment: That is a complicated fix, because you need some way to tell the 'grid' which textfield you want to receive the number. I would consider that a separate question from this one.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function:

```
  $('.showGrid').on('click', function(e)

    {

        if ($('#optionTypeTbl').css("display") == "table") {

            $('#optionTypeTbl').hide();

        } else {

            $('#optionTypeTbl').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#optionTypeTbl').css("display", "table");

        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

with:

```
$('.showGrid,.showGridRow').live("click", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     if ($('#optionTypeTbl').css("display") == "table") {
        $('#optionTypeTbl').hide();
     } else {
        $('#optionTypeTbl').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#optionTypeTbl').css("display", "table");
     }
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

See [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8cKm/11/)

Comment: Why go back to `.live` when you already have `.on`? (Granted jQuery converts one to the other internally, but still.)

Comment: I noticed that the `.showGridRow` is not binded to a click event so i combined the two selectors and bind the click event to them and it worked fine.

Comment: Hi, the only problem is that if I click on the "Open Grid" links in a row and select an option, it is suppose to change the value in that row's textbox not the value on the top textbox

Answer (score 0):

For the rows that get added you will need to use .live() as that watches the dom for updates and attaches the function to the event. So you can do some thing like.

```
$('.showGridRow').live(function(event){
event.preventDefault;
alert('code goes here');
});
```

You also need to use a variable to store which input you wish to update the value of. So you do some thing like this in your options pop up function.

```
input_box = $(this).parent().find('input');
```

Then use input_box.val(); latter inside of your option select callback.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TeqTe/) for a working demo.

Comment: it doesn't open the grid if I click on Open Grid on any of the rows